# Failed to kill a process as its user, sudo, and root. What else could I have tried?

Tags: server, bash, process, clamav, zimbra

I was trying to restart a program named `clamd` that was misbehaving, without restarting the server. It has a utility for controlling it, but that failed to work, so I tried using `kill` as the owner of the process, and **root** when that failed.

In the below image, you can see that the PID never changes, which I interpret as the process never having been stopped or restarted.

I was unsuccessful and wound up restarting the server.

What else should I have tried?

[image: Various commands used in bash while trying to kill clamd when it was it was no longer able to communicate with the Zimbra processes it lives to serve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have tried

```
kill -1 6533
```

this sends SIGHUP to the process. Depending on the program it will re-read it's configs after receiving the SIGHUP. Not sure if this would of worked in your case but it doesn't hurt to try before restarting.

default kill just sends 15 SIGTERM. which just sends a signal to stop what it is processing.

you can get a list of them like this

```
kill -l
```

will show you all the signals you can use.

Comment: I actually read that man page, and must have misunderstood it. I didn't try that because I thought I would kill all processes. I'll try it out when I have a chance. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

Using was sufficient.

```
kill -9 6533
```

Thank you for the `kill -l` tip:

```
~$ kill -l
 1) SIGHUP   2) SIGINT   3) SIGQUIT  4) SIGILL   5) SIGTRAP
 6) SIGABRT  7) SIGBUS   8) SIGFPE   9) SIGKILL 10) SIGUSR1
11) SIGSEGV 12) SIGUSR2 13) SIGPIPE 14) SIGALRM 15) SIGTERM
16) SIGSTKFLT   17) SIGCHLD 18) SIGCONT 19) SIGSTOP 20) SIGTSTP
21) SIGTTIN 22) SIGTTOU 23) SIGURG  24) SIGXCPU 25) SIGXFSZ
26) SIGVTALRM   27) SIGPROF 28) SIGWINCH    29) SIGIO   30) SIGPWR
31) SIGSYS  34) SIGRTMIN    35) SIGRTMIN+1  36) SIGRTMIN+2  37) SIGRTMIN+3
38) SIGRTMIN+4  39) SIGRTMIN+5  40) SIGRTMIN+6  41) SIGRTMIN+7  42) SIGRTMIN+8
43) SIGRTMIN+9  44) SIGRTMIN+10 45) SIGRTMIN+11 46) SIGRTMIN+12 47) SIGRTMIN+13
48) SIGRTMIN+14 49) SIGRTMIN+15 50) SIGRTMAX-14 51) SIGRTMAX-13 52) SIGRTMAX-12
53) SIGRTMAX-11 54) SIGRTMAX-10 55) SIGRTMAX-9  56) SIGRTMAX-8  57) SIGRTMAX-7
58) SIGRTMAX-6  59) SIGRTMAX-5  60) SIGRTMAX-4  61) SIGRTMAX-3  62) SIGRTMAX-2
63) SIGRTMAX-1  64) SIGRTMAX
```